# Webpage is not working as expected in Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I did a webpage http://pablosspcv.freeoda.com/ to put my CV (is in spanish) in firefox works as I expected, but in Safari, the lists can get crazy, the div parts don't keep on the center. I don't know what shoud I do with the browsers

---

I could fix 80% of the problem, the solution appart of the ones given, was also the tab, I had to change the editor to fix that
Now, the only thing to solve is the list, in firefox, everything is perfect, but in safari not, the modified  values the bullets are out in safari but not if firefox.

thanks

Comment: `align` attribute is long deprecated; use `margin:auto;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of your problems are your CSS file. You need to fix the properties on the file.

```
#title_1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 700px;
}

#prof_photo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
    height: 100px;
}

#personal_data{
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
}

#desarrollo{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 580px;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: No, it didn't help, i fixed that part, but doesn't work, only still working in firefox, and was supposed to appear an image, but it doesn't. thank you anyways

Comment: I was seeing your website and did you find the problem? Everything is good for what i see and i have only one suggestion... 
Change that background on your CV because you cannot read well.. But i understood the concept and i suggest to change to another background pattern to be more readable.

Comment: At the end was solved, sorry if I didn't put the ticket. Yes I did also I used the W3C validator. The background can get stock of the Internet is slow but I put a white newspaper

Answer (score 0):

The CSS for your container `#desarollo` contains `width: 580`.
You need to add "px" -> `width: 580px`
(BTW You also forgot this in some other spots)

Comment: I tried to put it, but in safari and iPhone, doesn't get fixed only in firefox

Comment: @historeas unknown: Sorry to tell you, but this (i.e. the "padding-right" settings you describe in your own answer ) is a completely wrong approach that will probably cause wrong display in other browsers (have youtried IE?). Use a table inside your #personal-data element.

Comment: I Just did it in that way because i want to see the bullet's list. But thank you for your advise